# Using @Formular to calculate entity attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

What I have is a classic spring boot, hibernate, postgres application.

I have an embedded entity called saveMetadata which I want to add a field named instanceCount to.

**Expected behavior**

When I load the entity from the database I would like to have the attribute `instanceCount` set to the number of entities with a `deleteTimestamp == nulll`  .

**Actual behaviour:**

I get an InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException.

```
"InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet;\ncaused by SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet;\ncaused by PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near \"as\"\n  Position: 1214;\ncaused by PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near \"as\"\n  Position: 1214"
```

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class SaveMetadata {

   @Column(updatable = false)
   private String referenceIdentifier;

   @Column
   private Instant deletedTimestamp;

   @Formula("count(deletedTimestamp==null") //todo work in progress, finish this
   private Long instanceCount;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your SQL query inside the @Formula annotation is wrong. You are missing the closing bracket too. I think it should look like the following:

```
@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SaveMetadata WHERE deletedTimestamp is NULL)")
private Long instanceCount;
```

Off-topic: I would consider changing the approach. Do you really need to store the value in each entity instance?

Comment: Thanks that worked!
I will consider if I could change that approach but right now I think I will need that value for the business logic.

Comment: How about calling the query placed in formula each time you need the value in the business logic then? This will result in less memory to be occupied.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is java, not sql syntax. Its better to use  `is null` though

Comment: @Martin does that change resolved your problem too?

Comment: @marcin.programuje this resolved the problem partly but my query was still broken.